# Applescript to not quit when erroring

Tags: applescript, rsync

I have an applescript that is used to copy a file (using rsync) from a source to a multitude of locations:

```
set Servers to {"afp://service.username:password@MACSERVER1.domain.com/Public/", "afp://service.username:password@MACSERVER2.domain.com/Public/",  "afp://service.username:password@MACSERVER3.domain.com/Public/",  "afp://service.username:password@MACSERVER4.domain.com/Public/",  "afp://service.username:password@MACSERVER5.domain.com/Public/"}
--these are constant so no need to change
set Source to "/Shared Items/Public/DeployStudio/Masters/HFS/Sierra.hfs.dmg"
set Destination to "/Volumes/Public/DeployStudio/Masters/HFS"
--the scripts that goes recursively through the list of servers
repeat with i from 1 to count of Servers
    set thisServer to item i of Servers
    --this will mount each server destination in turn creating a /Volumes/Public folder
    mount volume thisServer
    --these are two rsync scripts which creates logfiles
    do shell script "/usr/bin/rsync -rlptD --log- file=/Users/username/Documents/logs/Sierra-rsync.log " & (quoted form of Source) & " " & (quoted form of Destination)
    --not sure this is needed but added this 5 sec delay to stop ejecting disk errors
    delay 5
    --eject the mounted volume so we don't have multiple Public folders
    tell application "Finder"
        eject disk "Public"
    end tell
end repeat
```

This works great and produces a log of what it does. Unless there is a problem. Then it will just quit. I would like to change it so it ignores errors and keeps going. Any ideas? Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To ignore errors in the repeat loop wrap the affected code in a `try` block

```
repeat with i from 1 to count of Servers
    set thisServer to item i of Servers
    try

      ...

    end try
end repeat
```

Comment: nice. many thanks. tell me, you can add -v or -vv before the --log to have a more detailed log ? thanks again

Comment: I'm not that familiar with rsync, please read the `man` page.